# Unable to show image icon with angular2-tinymce

Tags: angular, tinymce

I want to insert image using tinymce edtor. I am using angular2-tinymce. Following are my settings:

```
    TinymceModule.withConfig({
      auto_focus: false, menubar: false, statusbar: false,
      plugins: ["link", "paste", "table", "advlist", "autoresize", "lists", "code", "image"],     
      toolbar: 'formatselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | image',
  }",
})
```

I am getting the following error on console:

[image]

Where am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

i have now updated `angular.json` with the following settings:

```
"node_modules/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.js"
```

Now another error is coming:

[image]

Comment: Could be an environment issue. Are you using `angular-cli` to bundle your app?

Comment: @AndrewHill i am using angular.json in angular 6

Comment: Thats your application configuration. How are you bundling / building your code?

Comment: @AndrewHill sorry for mis-understanding. i am using ng-serve to build the application as i am testing this in the local machine with angular-cli

Comment: Okay. angular2-tinymce requires tinymce to run. Have you run both `npm install --save tinymce` and `npm install --save angular2-tinymce`?

Comment: @AndrewHill not yet. i have used npm install angular2-tinymce --save only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196357/discussion-between-nimit-joshi-and-andrew-hill).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I've followed the steps defined below:

**Step 1:** Paste the following line in the module:

```
import 'tinymce/plugins/image';
```

**Step 2:** Update the tinymce config in module with the following lines:

```
plugins: ['image', 'code'],      
  min_height:400,
  file_picker_types: 'image', 
  file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
        var input = document.createElement('input') as HTMLInputElement;
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
        input.onchange = function() {
          var res = <HTMLInputElement>this;
          var file:File = res.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function () {
            var base64 = reader.result.toString();
            // call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
            cb(base64, { title: file.name });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        };

        input.click();
      },
toolbar: 'formatselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
```

That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely missing the `tinymce` dependency that `angular2-tinymce` relies on.

Run the following:

```sh
npm install --save tinymce angular2-tinymce
```

[Make sure you have followed all necessary steps in their usage docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tinymce). It looks like you need to copy some assets over to your assets folder too.

Comment: Sorry Andrew.. i can not accept this answer. i've not installed the tinymce also. I've resolved it.